# All real numbers that have more than 1 representation in IEEE-754 of single precision

Tags: cpu-architecture

the question is as follows :

> Write down all the real numbers that have more than 1 representation in IEEE-754 of single precision.

Now, considering +0 and -0 are different, are there any numbers that have this property?

Answer (score 1):

There are none.

The IEEE754 representation is *canonical*, which means that all numbers have precisely one representation if any, and no others.

#### Format of an IEEE754 single-precision floating-point number

```
31                             0
seeeeeeeemmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
```

Mapping to

(-1)^s  *  2^(eeeeeeee - 127)   *   1.mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm  (binary)

#### Proof of uniqueness of representation

- The sign is encoded in the sign bit, `s`. Two putatively different representations of the same real number must have the same value of `s`, because only that field controls the sign.
- The location of the most-significant `1`-bit, in digit positions left from the decimal comma, is encoded in biased format in the eight `eeeeeeee` exponent bits.  Two putatively different representations of the same real number must have the same value of `eeeeeeee`, because only that field controls the position of the most significant 1-bit.
- The 23 bits immediately below the most-significant `1`-bit are encoded in the mantissa (`mmmm...`). Two putatively different representations of the same real number would have to have the same mantissa value, because only that field controls the 23 bits immediately below the most-significant `1`-bit of the real number.

The conclusion is a contradiction. Two putatively different representations of a same real number would have to have the same sign, exponent and mantissa; In other words they must be identical.

This discussion ignores all the special values, like infinities, NaNs and denormals.